# Correct usage of jstranslator.xml

Tags: module, magento-1, configuration, localisation, third-party-module

I'm attempting to translate the error messages returned by the Postcode Anywhere module. They're displayed in browser alerts, so are created in JavaScript.

I managed to translate one using the inline script method as below:

```
alert( Translator.translate(error) );

Translator.add('PostalCode Required', '<?php echo $this->__('Translated text here'); ?>');
```

I don't really like that though because it means I have inline JavaScript, and a translation held within a template file when all my other translations are held in the global locale folder. In an attempt to make this cleaner, I've tried to use the newer jstranslate method but I can't get it functioning correctly.

Edit: Here's a link to the tutorial I followed: http://en.herveguetin.com/translate-javascript-with-jstranslator-xml.html

I have a module config.xml defining a module like so (Client is used to replace the real name for privacy purposes):

```
<modules>
    <Client_PostcodeAnywhere>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Client_PostcodeAnywhere>
</modules>
```

Inside the frontend -> layout sections of the config.xml file I have added:

```
<jstranslate>
    <file>jstranslator.xml</file>
</jstranslate>
```

Inside the frontend section of the config.xml I have added:

```
<translate>
    <modules>
        <client_postcodeanywhere>
            <files>
                <default>Client_PostcodeAnywhere.csv</default>
            </files>
        </client_postcodeanywhere>
    </modules>
</translate>
```

I have created the jstranslator.xml file in the same location as the module config.xml file:

```
<jstranslator>
    <client-postcodeanywhere-required translate="message" module="client_postcodeanywhere">
        <message>PostalCode Required</message>
    </client-postcodeanywhere-required>
</jstranslator>
```

I have created the Client_PostcodeAnywhere.csv file in my fr_FR folder within global locale folder (translating English to French):

```
"PostalCode Required","Translated text here"
```

I don't get a translation after doing this and I don't know why. Does anyone understand what the xml tags in the jstranslator file need to be? Mine is called 'client-postcodeanywhere-required' but I don't even know what that means.

Comment: Can anyone explain what the tags in <jstranslator> actually mean? For example, <client-postcodeanywhere-required> is just something I made up.

Comment: It doesn't matter, just make up something that makes sense to you and is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example code does work. I think I may have had a mismatch in naming somewhere but this is functioning as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

### Requirements

- A module must be declared
- This module must be ready to receive translations (.csv files +
  Helpers and translate node must be declared in the module's
  config.xml)

Comment: The module is declared, see the second code block. That's part of a module config.xml. The 3rd, 4th and 5th code blocks are where I have followed instructions on using jstranlate to setup the module to receive translations. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is Helper defined?

Comment: What is a *translate node* and how is it declared in `config.xml`?